# ProgressDialog misbehaviour after activity rotation

Tags: android, progressdialog

I need to show a `ProgressDialog` which will show even after rotation of activity. After rotation of the activity `progressDialog` is keep displaying, it doesn't get dismissed even after I signal it to dismiss by invoking `idle()`. what could be the reason. Thanks in advance!

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int command = 1;
    private final String action = "show-progress-dialog";
    private boolean showProgress = false;
    private volatile ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            if (message.getData() != null && message.what == command) {
                if (message.getData().getBoolean("show")) {
                    showProgressDialog();
                } else {
                    safeDismiss();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean("showProgress", showProgress);
        safeDismiss();
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        showProgress = savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean("showProgress", false);
        if (showProgress) {
            showProgressDialog();
        }
    }

    protected void busy() {
        if (Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.myLooper()) {//in ui thread
            showProgressDialog();
            return;
        }
        Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage(command);
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putBoolean("show", true);
        data.putString("action", action);
        message.setData(data);
        message.sendToTarget();
    }

    protected void idle() {
        if (Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.myLooper()) {//in ui thread
            safeDismiss();
            return;
        }
        Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage(command);
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putBoolean("show", false);
        data.putString("action", action);
        message.setData(data);
        message.sendToTarget();
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        safeDismiss();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "please wait…", true, false);
        showProgress = true;
    }

    private void safeDismiss() {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            showProgress = false;
            progressDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this activity is an `abstract` Activity. if this is the only solution, i have to add it to all sub activities. besides google [does not encourage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) to do so.

Comment: Solved this yet?

Comment: Nope, actually I was looking for a solution rather than override `onConfigurationChanged`. anyway thanks [IntelliJ Amiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3395198/intellij-amiya)

Comment: Solved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Read [**`android:configChanges`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config)

> When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut
>   down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this
>   attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Then

```
   @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

      if (progressDialog.isShowing()) 
      {
        progressDialog .dismiss();
      }
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
       if (progressDialog.isShowing()) 
      {
        progressDialog .dismiss();
      }
    }
}
```